# Is ValidationException a runtime exception or not?

Tags: java

Can anyone please give me information about it. I cant really uderstand the type of this Exception.

Thank you

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception{

 public ValidationException(){
 super("There was a problem when validating data");
 }

 public ValidationException(String message){
 super(message);
 }

 public ValidationException(String message, Throwable throwable){
 super(message, throwable);
 }

 public ValidationException(Throwable throwable){
 super(throwable);
 }
}
```

Comment: it extends Exception, not RuntimeException.

Comment: Thank you! What does this mean with regards to throws clauses as well as catch blocks?

Comment: an exception must be handled by the caller. either by rethrowing the exception or catching it. Runtime exceptions dont need to be handled directly

Comment: [The Java Tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a "runtime exception" in the (fatuous) sense that it is an exception that occurs at runtime.  But that is true for *all* Java exceptions ... apart from bugs in the compiler, etcetera.
2. It is not a subclass of `RuntimeException`.  You have declared it as a subclass of `Exception` and `Exception` is not a subclass of `RuntimeException`.  (In fact, the reverse is true:  `RuntimeException` is a subclass of `Exception`!)
3. It is a *checked* exception because it is not a subclass of `RuntimeException` (or `Error`).

Since it is a checked exception, the Java rules about checked exceptions apply.  For example, any method that throws or propagates<sup>1</sup> your exception must declare that it `throws` this exception, or an exception that is a superclass of this exception.

---

<sup>1 - Technically, the JLS describes this as an *abnormal termination* of the method body with this exception as the abnormal termination *reason*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Exception, and RuntimeException is that we need to wrap a Exception in a try/catch block. A RuntimeException does not need to be caught, but it is just as lethal as an Exception.

```
public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
       new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e){
           System.out.println("Uncaught Exception " + e);
        }
     });

     try{
        throwException();
     }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Caught Exception " + e);
     }


     try{
        throwRuntimeException();
     }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Caught RuntimeException " + e);
     }

     //unchecked, no need to wrap int try/catch
     throwRuntimeException();
  }

  public static void throwException() throws Exception {
     throw new Exception();
  }

  public static void throwRuntimeException() {
     throw new RuntimeException();
  }

}
```

Take this example above. The output is this:

> Caught Exception java.lang.Exception 
>   Caught RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException 
>   Uncaught Exception java.lang.RuntimeException

As you can tell, the call to throwRuntimeException() gets thrown, and since there is no try/catch block it has no idea how to handle it. This crashes the thread and since there is an UncaughtExceptionHandler it gets called.

Then there is also Error which I won't go into since I don't know much about it besides that JVM throws it. OutOfMemoryError is an example.